# Math puzzle: 8,5=100

Tags: mathematics, pattern

I'm a bit stuck with this puzzle ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmRLt.jpg))

```
8,5=100
10,4=80
16,2=?
```

I've tried 40,52,62,68 but no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My suggestion would be

> 32

Following the rule

> $a,b = \frac{ab^2}{2}$

Although bear in mind

> Because we only have two previous equations there may be many valid answers that work.

Comment: Brilliant! I'll accept this answer in 10 minutes. Many thanks!